# Error in custom build in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual studio 2015 to work on a project initially developed in Visual studio 2010. Getting errors while building in the custom build section, not sure how to fix it.
[warning code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nisLv.jpg)
[image: error code fragment]

Comment: "Intermediate Directory" is one of the settings on the first screen of the project properties. So, does it end with a slash? Or could you add one?

Comment: @Bo Persson, not sure which slash it is referring to..

Answer (score 1):

Look in the project properties. There is a setting for Intermediate Directory:

[image: Property Pages]

Does it end in a slash in your project? If not, can you add one?